# Xamarin Forms + Azure Reading Column

Tags: c#, forms, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios

[image]

I just dived in to Xamarin Forms and using Azure. 
I am able to successfully call the row from the database but it's displaying something into the ListView instead of what I want it to display.

[image: screenshot of the Azure table]

My codes:

```
private async void generateList()
{
    var clientUsers = await  App.MobileService.GetTable<iSoftTicket.Model.TblUser>().Where(u => u.uc_category == "Client").ToListAsync();
            lvClient.ItemsSource = clientUsers;
}
```

I want it to display the column with Gulfden on it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have a binding issue with your ViewCell... maybe you need a custom cell  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#customcells

Comment: Have you solved your problem？

Comment: @Land I have. Sorry I got busy. I used your answer and accepted it. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. Forgot that one. There, done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your ListView's ItemTemplate(e.g. ViewCell) and then add some label to display your data like:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Admin}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Tickets}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Clients}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I notice that you have set your listview's ItemSource, please make sure your model's property names is Corresponding to the Binding name in the XAML, you can refer to my sample in code behind:

```
ObservableCollection<MyModel> list = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new MyModel { Admin = "admin" + i, Clients = "client", Tickets = "tickets" });
}
MyListView.ItemsSource = list;

public class MyModel
{
    public string Admin { set; get; }
    public string Tickets { get; set; }
    public string Clients { get; set; }
}
```